# A word for something impossible or near impossible to do but fun to try

Tags: single-word-requests

A word that describes something impossible or near impossible to do but fun to try. One example I can think of is trying to lick one's elbow. A contortionist can do it but not everyone else. We sure give it a try despite knowing we can't do it.

Comment: Does it have to be fun to try? Sometimes there are painful things that people attempt to achieve like find 'happiness' :D I am thinking of the term 'sisyphus-ical' to describe the act of doing something impossibly frustrating, or just futile but it doesn't really indicate the level of fun involved.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps the word is not specific enough, but I'd simply suggest **challenging**.

Something *challenging* is demanding, so perhaps it doesn't quite stretch to being "near impossible", however a *challenge* suggests something which is "fun to try". I suppose it depends whether you are looking for an obscure or common word. HTH

Comment: Yes, a "fun challenge" is what I'd say.

Comment: Please explain why *challenging* is the word you'd suggest.

Comment: oh, did I get downvoted for not explaining my suggestion?

Comment: Welcome to English Language & Usage. This answer was flagged as low-quality because of its length and content. As Matt suggested, please try to elaborate on why you think challenging works. Otherwise, your answer could be deleted by voting.

Comment: I've provided some clarification - hope that's more suitable - apologies, I'm new to the forum, I was just trying to help!

Comment: @Gonja just try harder next time and you'll be okay.

Answer (score 1):

You can use **Conundrum** or **Enigma** to refer to difficult but interesting problems.

As per google-

> conundrum- confusing and difficult problem or question.
>
> a question asked for amusement, typically one with a pun in its answer; a riddle.

Answer (score 0):

If referencing Sisyphusical, the word origin coming out of Sisyphus. The defining should be roughly, though most accurately with the following: 
  An impossible task to accomplish, yet repeatedly attempted as that of a challenge, with demanding physical exertion. Mostly that as being damned to repeat attempting for an eternity.

Answer (score -2):

Your ***endeavors*** are ***futile***. Such a word simply does not exist.